# How to plot data categorically with facet_wrap when values of one category are updated? Keeping both on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which is something like this:

```
#sample dataframe
set.seed(42)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-30"), "day")
n <- length(dates)
dat <- data.frame(created_at = dates,
                  category = rep(LETTERS[1:4], n/2),
                  With_Outlier = sample(18:100, n, replace=TRUE),
                  count = sample(10:40, n, replace=TRUE))
```

I am using the following code to plot the data in a way I desire:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = created_at)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = With_Outlier, colour = paste0(category,"  With_Outliers")))+
  geom_line(aes(y = count, colour = paste0(category,"  Value Counts")))+
  facet_wrap(~ category, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(title = 'Data Visualization',
       x = 'Month',
       y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y", expand = expansion(0,0))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text=element_text(size=13),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.6, "lines"),
        panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"), legend.position="bottom")+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 2)+ labs(color = NULL)
```

And this is the output I am getting:
[image]

Now I do some kind of operation on the data and for `category` **B**, the values are updated (I'd call it **Clean_Values** and **Clean_Count**, for ease, I save them in another dataframe). For the rest of the categories, everything remains same. This way, I need to plot two lines for two columns just for Category B.

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some work and came up with this solution, posting here so it might help someone else.

Creating sample new dataframe with **Clean_Values** and **Clean_Count**.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(created_at = dates,
    category = rep(LETTERS[2:2], n/2),
    Clean_Values = sample(200:400, n, replace=TRUE),
    Clean_Count = sample(500:600, n, replace=TRUE))
)
```

Now to plot the data, I've added following two lines:

```
geom_line(data = dat1, aes(x = created_at, y = Clean_Values, colour = paste0("  Clean Values")))+
  geom_line(data = dat1, aes(x = created_at, y = Clean_Count, colour = paste0("  Clean Count")))+
```

Here's the complete code:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = created_at)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = With_Outlier, colour = paste0(category,"  With_Outliers")))+
  geom_line(aes(y = count, colour = paste0(category,"  Value Counts")))+
  facet_wrap(~ category, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_line(data = dat1, aes(x = created_at, y = Clean_Values, colour = paste0("  Clean Values")))+
  geom_line(data = dat1, aes(x = created_at, y = Clean_Count, colour = paste0("  Clean Count")))+
  labs(title = 'Data Visualization',
       x = 'Month',
       y = 'Count') +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y", expand = expansion(0,0))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text=element_text(size=13),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.6, "lines"),
        panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"), legend.position="bottom")+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 2)+ labs(color = NULL)
```

And below is the output with two new lines as desired also in the legend too:

[image]